# Active Directory Administrative Center - resize membership part

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

User can be a member of 3 groups at most to be visible in ADAC without scrolling.

But in reality, users are members of 5, 10 even 20 groups. We have to scroll the "member of" list to check the membership. Old ADUC gives better view. Or there is a solution to resize the window (and ideally fix it), so there is no need to scroll every time?

[image: ADAC showing only small fragment of user's membership]

Comment: PowerShell all the things. ->  [`Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617259.aspx)

Comment: Taking it a step further (if you really like GUI's): In `powershell_ise.exe` -> `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership | Out-GridView`

Comment: Thanks for your time to propagate powershell. But let's go back on topic, anyone?

Comment: I have a bit of a love/hate relationship with the ADAC GUI. Like its promise, but its design and performance aren't always great. Since you mentioned ADUC, can you still use that?

Comment: yep I can use old, but new thing is a new thing:)

Answer (score 1):

Alas, there is not.

It seems the only solution is to find an alternative such as the old ADUC, or PowerShell.